# Kubernetes Dashboard is not available

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-dashboard

This is my first time what I'm installing Kubernetes and trying to understand how it works. First problem that I can't solve is opening Dashboard via HTTP protocol using `proxy` by visting the URL from documentation:

http://localhost:8001/api/v1/namespaces/kubernetes-dashboard/services/https:kubernetes-dashboard:/proxy/

Browser's respond is: *This site can’t be reached. Localhost refused to connect.*

---

### Little bit about my environment!

**I've started with virtual machines equipped with:**

1. Master: 2 VCPU, 4GB RAM,  Ubuntu 18.04
2. Worker1: 1 VCPU, 2GB RAM,  Ubuntu 18.04
3. Worker1: 1 VCPU, 2GB RAM,  Ubuntu 18.04

All running and connected to a private network.

So far I followed the instructions to setup production environment by [installing kubeadm](https://kubernetes.io/docs/setup/production-environment/tools/kubeadm/install-kubeadm/). Than [created a single control-plane cluster with kubeadm](https://kubernetes.io/docs/setup/production-environment/tools/kubeadm/create-cluster-kubeadm/) without joining any nodes yet.

**Environment that I created is:**

- Kubernetes version 1.15 (run as *root* user)
- Docker version 18.09.9 (run as *root* user)
- Calico version 3.8 (run as *non-root* user)
- Dashboard version 2.0.0-beta4 (run as *non-root* user)

---

All seems to be running.

[image: installing kubernetes dashboard]

What I can is to see some respond when I load

https://master-IP:6443/api/v1/namespaces/kubernetes-dashboard/services/https:kubernetes-dashboard:/proxy/

[image: installing kubernetes dashboard]

So what I can't is to open/load Kubernetes Dashboard UI using proxy over HTTP protocol by [official Kubernetes Dashboard documentation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/access-application-cluster/web-ui-dashboard/).

---

P.S. One thing is unclear to me when setting up a new user to log in to Dashboard using bearer token tied to this user. Shouldn't the value of `namespace` be changed from `kube-system` to `kubernetes-dashboard` according to the [changelog of v2.0.0-beta1](https://github.com/kubernetes/dashboard/releases/tag/v2.0.0-beta1)?

Comment: Please, update the post with he output from `kubectl describe --namespace=kubernetes-dashboard pod $POD`, where `$POD` is the name of the dashboard pod. Also try to run command starting from `http`, not `https`: `http://master-IP:6443/api/v1/namespaces/kubernetes-dashboard/services/https:kubernetes-dashboard:/proxy/`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see that you would like to access the dashboard from your laptop. What you should do is create an admin account called k8s-admin:

```
$ kubectl --namespace kube-system create serviceaccount k8s-admin
$ kubectl create clusterrolebinding k8s-admin --serviceaccount=kube-system:k8s-admin --clusterrole=cluster-admin
```

Then setup kubectl on your laptop / workstation:
For example for macOS it looks like this (see [documentation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/tools/install-kubectl/)):

```
$ brew install kubernetes-cli
```

Setup a proxy to your workstation. Create a `~/.kube` directory on your laptop and then scp the `~/.kube/config` file from the k8s (Kubernetes) master to your `~/.kube` directory.

Then get the authentication token you need to connect to the dashboard:

```
$ kubectl -n kube-system describe secret $(kubectl -n kube-system get secret | grep k8s-admin | awk '{print $1}')
```

Store this token, you’ll need it to access the Kubernetes dashboard. Now start the proxy:

```
$ kubectl proxy
```

Now open the dashboard by going to:

```
http://localhost:8001/api/v1/namespaces/kubernetes-dashboard/services/https:kubernetes-dashboard:/proxy/
```

You should see the `Token` option and then copy-paste the token from the prior step and Sign-In.

You can follow this [tutorial](https://medium.com/@salqadri/build-your-own-multi-node-kubernetes-cluster-with-monitoring-346a7e2ef6e2).

Comment: Honestly I had no idea that `kubectl` can also be run from a local machine like my laptop to comunicate by data provided in `config` file copied from file `$HOME/.kube/config` from master node. I though that it can only run from Kubernetes environment because `kubectl` is one of the packages that must be installed on remote machines. **So my fault was that I run `kubectl proxy` from master node.** Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure why you cannot see it using proxy. However, I was able to expose Dashboard on one the IP of one my VMs using NodePort. You need to edit Dashboard's service and replace 'ClusterIP' with 'NodePort'.

Comment: This way of accessing Dashboard is only recommended for [development environments in a single node setup](https://github.com/kubernetes/dashboard/wiki/Accessing-Dashboard---1.7.X-and-above), which seems to be fine. Well, I rather not when I understand how it works a little more. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you are trying to access your kubernetes cluster locally through your laptop and it is throwing a "*This site can’t be reached. Localhost refused to connect.*" .

You will need to create a tunnel from your local machine to the instance where your i am putting in a sample tunnel command `ssh -N -L 8001:127.0.0.1:8001 user@ipadress`